# I want to take array of 30 and use 3 threads that will sum the 30 values.Each thread adds in groups of 10

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading

New to threads. I am trying to have the 3 threads add in groups of 10.  The multiplication portions works but I am only getting the "thread 2 is done without the sum being performed in subTotal.  What am I missing please?

"there should be 3 workerBeeTask n-methods to get the array out of the object and add up the 10 array elements and write the total back onto the object subTotal n-properties"

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    int[] theArray = new int[] { 43, 12, 93, 40, 1, 25, 4, 63, 92, 86, 46, 48, 18, 75, 82, 97, 89, 66, 49, 7, 62, 24, 47, 67, 88, 2, 74, 99, 23, 80 }; //array

    // instantiate an instance of the AddArrayData class and call it taxi
    AddArrayData taxi = new AddArrayData(theArray);
    // its job is just to hold data. set eachof the 3 subTotal-n properties to 0
    int subTotal1 = 0; //sT-1 holds the value 0
    int subTotal2 = 0;
    int subTotal3 = 0;
    bool othersNotDone = true;  // bool variable to use as gate while waiting for 2 other threads            
    Thread workerBeeTask1 = new Thread(AddSomeNumbers);           
    Thread workerBeeTask2 = new Thread(AddSomeNumbers);            
    Thread workerBeeTask3 = new Thread(AddSomeNumbers);
    // start the workerBeeTask-1 method, passing in your instance of the AddArrayData class
    workerBeeTask1.Start(taxi);            
    workerBeeTask2.Start(taxi);
    workerBeeTask3.Start(taxi);
    Console.WriteLine("Thread1: now waiting for other two threads");
    while (othersNotDone)  // thread 1 will wait here until other threads are done
    {   othersNotDone = false;
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // give CPU cycles back by sleeping for 1 seconds.
        if (workerBeeTask2.IsAlive || workerBeeTask3.IsAlive)   // test if both threads are done yet?
        {   othersNotDone = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Thread 1 waiting!");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Thread 1: other 2 thread are now done");
    Console.WriteLine("Thread 1: now I can continue, assuming data I needed has been calculated");
    // use the data in the object that the other 2 threads have calucated and updated
    int answer = taxi.AddArrayTotal + taxi.MultiplyTotal;
    Console.WriteLine("the sum of the added and the muliplied array is {0}", answer);
    Console.ReadLine();
}  // just wait)

private static void AddSomeNumbers(object inputObject)
{
    AddArrayData localData = (AddArrayData)inputObject;
    int tempTotal = 0;
    // now build a loop and total the value of the array values in the array, in that object
    for (int i = 0; i < localData.theArray.Length; i++)
    }
        tempTotal = tempTotal + localData.theArray[i];
    }
    localData.AddArrayTotal = tempTotal;
    Console.WriteLine("Thread: 2 done.");
}
```

Multiplication works fine

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to perform array addition in parts using multiple threads. You can use three parallel threads to sum parts of an array. The below code sums up the original array in three threads that target elements 0-9, 10-19 and 20-29 and stores them in the partialSums[] so that they can be used as required.

```
int[] theArray = new int[] { 43, 12, 93, 40, 1, 25, 4, 63, 92, 86, 46, 48, 18, 75, 82, 97, 89, 66, 49, 7, 62, 24, 47, 67, 88, 2, 74, 99, 23, 80 }; //array
int[] partialSums = new int[3];

// Parallely start three threads that sum parts of the original array in multiples of 10
Parallel.For(0, 3, (counter) =>
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = counter * 10; i < (counter + 1) * 10; i++)
        sum += theArray[i];
    partialSums[counter] = sum;
});

// Print the result
foreach (var sum in partialSums)
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Output:
459
577
566

Comment: Thank you.  Can you direct me to any materials that can supplement my understanding.  I really want to understand Threads.

Comment: @BrendaM you can start with the TPL here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx. If my answer helped solved your problem, you can accept it as the right answer. Thanks!